Nodemailer Works in Development but Fails in Production – How Can I Fix This?
I'm using Nodemailer in my Node.js app with Gmail's SMTP to send emails. It works fine in my development environment, but in production, emails aren’t being sent. I’ve set up my environment variables and confirmed they are loaded correctly. Here’s the code:
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer");

exports.sendEmail = async (options) => {
  const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SMPT_MAIL,
      pass: process.env.SMPT_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.SMPT_MAIL,
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    html: options.message,
  };

  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};


Using Gmail as a SMTP transport is fraught and subject to the heuristics that google use to detect any automated use, which they don't support and will block. It's likely that your production server triggers these heuristics, while your local machine looks like a real person. Nodemailer has a page about this: https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Ultimately for any serious use you should look to use a SMTP service meant for such use. There are a great many out there, e.g. MailGun, MailJet, SendGrid off the top of my head. I've used mailersend.net for simple contact forms in the past with no issue, though you should do your own research to find what works for your usecase

Ideally, you would use your own SMTP server and not rely on any third-party service at all

@JaromandaX It depends, but almost always I would disagree. Running a SMTP service properly and responsibly is more than throwing a SMTP server on a machine and calling it a day. Unless you're at a large scale it's probably not worth it and better to use a third-party service who has done that work and is maintaining it

@JaromandaX  Thankyou for giving this question some time but can you give me a code for reference that would work in my case if possible.

@Anmolahuja - there is no code for installing and running your own SMTP server

@ChrisM - I did say ideally

@Anmolahuja This isn't something for which a simple code snippet can help you and StackOverflow isn't a place to get free work on your project. I've given some pointers above but you'll have to figure out the general approach yourself or get professional assistance.

@JaromandaX Fair. I just always like to give context when making recommendations
